# Using featured image of blog archive page

Tags: php, post-thumbnails, blog

On my custom wordpress theme, I am using the featured image thumbnail for all of my pages to be the header of the page.

I've created a page called "blog" and using it as the archive ( via settings -> reading -> selecting "blog" for post display page ) reading, but when I try to use the featured image of that page, it tries to display ALL of the featured images from the blogs, not just my one archive page how I want.

I'm pretty sure it's a matter of altering the if statement to only show the thumb of the archive page, but I'm not sure how.

Here is my code on `index.php`

```php
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <section>
        <?php 
        if ( have_posts() ) : 
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                // post thumbnail
                if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if Thumbnail exists
                    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
                    <a class="page-thumb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                        <div class="page-thumb" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $url ?>');"></div>
                    </a>
                <?php 
                endif;
                // article
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <h1 class="page-h1 animate-reveal">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </h1>
                </article> <!-- /article -->
    
            <?php 
            endwhile;
        endif; ?>
    
    </section>
    <main role="main" aria-label="Content" class="page-bg page-margin">
    <!-- section -->
    <section>
        <h1 class="archive-h1">News</h1>
        <?php 
        get_template_part( 'loop' );
        get_template_part( 'pagination' ); ?>
    </section><!-- /section -->
</main>

<?php 
get_footer(); ?>
```

EDITS using answer #1

complete index.php file below

```
 <?php get_header(); ?>

    <main role="main" aria-label="Content" class="page-bg page-margin">



        <!-- section -->
        <section>
            <?php 
                $page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' ); 
                if ($page_for_posts && has_post_thumbnail($page_for_posts)) {
                    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $page_for_posts);
                    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb_id );
                if ( have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <!-- post thumbnail -->
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if Thumbnail exists ?>
            <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
                <a class="page-thumb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <div class="page-thumb" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $url ?>');"></div>
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <!-- article -->
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <h1 class="page-h1 animate-reveal">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </h1>
                
                </article>
            <!-- /article -->

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php else : ?>
            <!-- article -->
            <!-- /article -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        
        <?php } ?>
            <h1 class="archive-h1">News</h1>

            <?php get_template_part( 'loop' ); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'pagination' ); ?>

        </section>
        <!-- /section -->
    </main>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grab the ID of the page you've set as your Posts page in Settings > Reading in order to access its properties. To do that, check for the page_for_posts option, which returns the ID:

```
$page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' ); 
if ($page_for_posts && has_post_thumbnail($page_for_posts) {
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $page_for_posts);
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb_id );
    //... the rest of your featured image display stuff here
}
```

This code should be placed outside of (before) the index.php loop which displays all your blog posts & their featured images, it doesn't replace it.

You can use this `$page_for_posts` ID to display other elements of that page, too, including the title, eg: `echo get_the_title($page_for_posts);`

EDIT:

Try this for your index.php; I'm assuming your actual posts loop is inside the 'loop' template part. This will just dump out an `<img>` tag at the top of the Posts page with that page's featured image.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <main role="main" aria-label="Content" class="page-bg page-margin">

        <!-- section -->
        <section>

        <?php 
        // Get the ID of the page set to Display Posts in Settings > Reading
        $page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' ); 

        // If that page ID exists, and that page has a Featured Image....
        if ($page_for_posts && has_post_thumbnail($page_for_posts)) {

            // Get the ID of that page's Featured Image
            $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $page_for_posts);

            // Display that image
            echo wp_get_attachment_image($thumb_id);
        } 

        // Display the page title if set; else use 'News'              
        if ($page_for_posts) {
          echo '<h1 class="archive-h1">' . get_the_title($page_for_posts) . '</h1>';
        } else {
          echo '<h1 class="archive-h1">News</h1>';
        }
        ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'loop' ); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'pagination' ); ?>

        </section>
        <!-- /section -->
    </main>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I use this function to output that featured image: [wp_get_attachment_image()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/) That function will output an `<img>` tag with scrset attributes for responsive images. If you'd rather have the page's featured image be displayed as a background image, you could still use `wp_get_attachment_url()` to get just the URL and use your `<div>` to display it, like so:

```
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url($thumb_id); ?>
<div class="page-thumb" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $url ?>');"></div>
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thanks. I'm still getting the same result, please view the edited version of the question above to see the full index.php with your edits.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If this isn't working, try echoing out the $page_for_posts to confirm it's the correct Page ID for the page set to display your posts, then echo out the $thumb_id to confirm it's the ID of the Featured Image for that page.